# What should I do if I am post-banned but I can not modify any of my bad questions to be good?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, post-ban, bad-questions

I know, I have three VERY bad questions on my Stack Overflow account. BUT! There is a problem. Those questions are REALLY BAD and I have no way of modifying them to good ones... I can only be un post-banned if my questions get upvoted. I would delete the bad ones but the help center says it wouldn't use anything... so what should I do? The questions are so bad that they can not get better without making the comments and answers not be right to the question... So? Please tell me what to do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What?! But why sooo much? How many UP-Votes does that question have to have so that the post-ban is over?

Comment: @RMR_MD _“If you are banned from asking questions, contributing quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68885/289905) enable you to ask questions again. However, **as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure**.”_ — from the same answer.

Comment: @user11567957 Creating a new account to get around a question ban would just result in your new account being question-banned as well.

Comment: @fbueckert , What does that mean? Oh, no. I am post-banned again. Did you report that?

Comment: It means someone abused the voting system by voting on your posts instead of judging their relative merit.  That sort of voting is checked for, and if found, reversed.  All they did was let you ask one more question, and it's now going to be that much harder to actually get out of it.

Comment: @fbueckert , why will it be harder to get out of it?

Comment: Because you now have another question that is also contributing to the ban.  Pity upvotes seem nice, but as you can see, don't actually help, and only make things worse.

Comment: The other question got deleted from someone and I can not undelete it and that question didn't have down votes. Ahhh, really the only thing I need is an answer to a question that I can not answer myself because I can't continue my coding else. It is a big problem I can not answer myself. Is it soo hard to lift the post-ban? Now I have to wait 6 months starting now. This is really sad. Why am I even on this WebSite?

Comment: @fbueckert , the post-ban actually just returned as you added your comment. Do you have to do something with that?

Comment: @RMR_MD The question ban is an entirely automated process. The upvotes you received earlier were enough to lift you out of it, but the deletion of your most recent question appears to have tipped you back into it. Unless fbueckert was one of those who voted to delete your question, then no, he had nothing to do with it.

Comment: OOOOH so I have to get one more or two upvotes to get un-post-banned? Oof. I will have to be better at editing the questions. Someone downvoted to another of my question. I think it was him tough this time. I need 3 upvotes for sure

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/62086105) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/61877739) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/61869315) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/61856849)

Comment: @SamuelLiew that's why it's best to use burner accounts. Rep makes no real difference when asking questions so apart from the hassle generating them it's a good option. Use answers to build up rep until you have enough to survive an downvote attack.

Comment: hmmm... well what do you mean I can't ask questions anymore? Like can't I ask questions even after the 6 months or can't I ask questions even if I have more up votes than down-votes? I mean I've got VERY MUCH MORE up-votes than down-votes and I still am post-banned

Comment: You can ask one question every six months, just as the existing answer says. Currently, your deleted questions, and the downvotes on them, outweigh the number of upvotes that your non-deleted questions have. If you can fix the deleted questions that Samuel Liew linked to, and have them undeleted, you can climb back out of the question ban.

Comment: Oooooh no.... the questions I asked there were VERY VERY BAD. I can not fix them as they are off topic and I already got comments and stuff like that... how in the world should I import my BAD questions? Have you read them?

Comment: I can't view your deleted questions; I don't have enough reputation. If they're truly unsalvageable, then I'm afraid there may well be nothing you can do.

Comment: oh, no... but only unless the up votes I'll get will be more than the down-votes I have, right? Well, that is pretty unlikely unless someone that I KNOW would help me. But there is no one...

Comment: I can't tell you how many upvotes you'll need to get out of the question ban. The specifics are hidden to prevent people from gaming the system. You'll just have to the best you can to improve your questions and hope that they gain the necessary upvotes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all of your guys support. I understand all of this now. But I will not create a burner account - at least not now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ban isn't actually a ban but a rate limit to one question every six months. Make sure each question is a really stellar one, you've got the next six months to polish it.

Having said that, your [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046304/i-am-trying-to-move-my-character-but-instead-of-that-something-else-happend) clearly can be improved...

> So. I am trying to move my character. I wrote it just like in a tutorial. It didn't work so I tried to fix it but just ruined other things. Can someone please tell me what the problem is? It would be also nice if someone would tell me how to resize the objects, buttons, etc when I maximize my Pygame Window? I don't know what the errors mean. Can someone please try this code on their own and then tell me what they mean and what to do? Here is the code:

1. Remove the initial “So,”. It doesn't add anything.
2. What tutorial?
3. What didn't work?
4. How did you try to fix it?
5. What other things were ruined?
6. What errors are you seeing?
7. What don't you understand about those errors?

Comment: I would do that but I got an answer and I do not know if I should edit it as I now already know what to do...

Comment: You know, I will do what you said. It is worth a try...

Comment: So basically... what you said in your answer, which was already acknowledged just a few minutes ago with "You know, I will do what you said"... I am so confused.

Comment: Oh, oof. I am confused too now. Well I'll just try to fix all of my BAD questions...

Comment: @RMR_MD - If you improve your deleted questions to a point, where they are acceptable, you can flag them so they are no longer deleted.

Comment: I deleted the bad questions and I could already undelete them.